# Cannot change options in Angular UI datepicker

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4ZL9l3BKVNZGcOCuTDo?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal that contains a directive that wraps a datepicker. For some reason the `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` is ignored as I cannot make the calendar NOT show the week numbers. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

  <div style="height:200px">
        <dir></dir>
  </div>

</script>
```

HTML directive

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"
       uib-datepicker-popup="" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope
        });

});

app.directive('dir', function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {
            control: '='
    };

    directive.templateUrl = 'dir.html';

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.opened = false;

        scope.dateOptions = {
            showWeeks: false
        };

        scope.open1 = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            scope.opened = true;
        };

      };

    return directive;

});
```

Comment: Probably your Modal is creating its own scope and hence the options variable is not accessible

Comment: I thought about that, however the opened variable is in the same scope and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your case, I assigned it to `myCtl` controller and worked quite well.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2p5JI2PEt6FFUdLAIZaH?p=preview)